# Getting SG300 setup from console to L3 switch with web access

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco SG300-28 switch with the latest firmware which is colocated.

My colocation facility has hooked up a KVM like device to the serial console, so I can ssh into the switch to configure it.

I'd like to do the following.

- Reset the switch to factory defaults
- Convert it to Layer 3 mode
- Make it so that it the web interface answers on the ip address the facility has given me can be logged into via a web browser.

(For the sake of examples please assume the web address is 203.0.113.66 and it's a /28.  The actual ip address is a real routable ip).

I've tried many permutations on snippets I've seen on the web, but haven't gotten the switch to serve its web interface.

If someone could provide me with an example of what to type, so I can get the switch working that would be great.

Comment: If your question was answered, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can `erase` the `startup-config` and `reload` to get the factory configuration.

I think you mean Layer-3, not Level 3, and it is a Layer-3 switch.

A best practice for security is to disable the HTTP server and HTTP secure-server in Cisco devices, but you can enable it with the `ip http server` command. You will need to have a configured IP address on the switch which you can reach for the web interface to work.

Without a complete network design, we can't begin to guess how you have it connected or your needs, and we would just be guessing on a proper configuration.

**Note:**

This is all very simple stuff for a switch, and I would *strongly* recommend you get someone who knows how to do this to configure it for you. It is not a simple thing like a home router, and it sounds like you don't have a firewall protecting it, which seems a very foolish idea.

Comment: What would you recommend for a firewall?

Comment: Unfortunately, product and resource recommendations are off-topic.